# How to customize default add content page

Tags: nodes

I want to customize the default add content page, more specifically, to get rid vertical tab in the bottom, and add explanation text to each field.

How can i do this?
what php file should i tinker ?
is there already some modules to to this ?

thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Renderable Elements](https://drupal.org/project/rel) module. If you've ever had any experience with [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds), it works exactly like that, but for forms like Add Content. You can change up the display, remove the vertical tabs below, etc.

For the explanation, each field comes with a description/help field that you can fill out. Now it depends on the admin theme you're using on how that text is displayed.

Comment: display suite is the best option for begginers

Comment: @KyleTaylored : Thank you for the info. Now I can get rid of the vertical tabs,add explanation text,and change the display by setting admin theme. However,after I eliminated the additional settings in the vertical tab,the created content is not automatically published (which is a side effect i like, because i want my site's user to post anything they want, but only I who have the authority to publish )